# Reescalar imagen con factor de escala en Python

Tags: python, opencv

Quiero redimensionar una imagen aplicando un factor de escala kesc y estoy usando la función de OpenCV `resize` de la siguiente manera:

(En este caso kesc = 0.2)

`k = kesc*img.shape`
`nuevo_tam = cv.resize(img, kesc)`

Sin embargo, me da error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' y no entiendo cómo podría solucionarlo.

Comment: `shape` te da 2 valores y al multiplicar obtienes una tupla y no un número

Comment: es que por lo visto el segundo parámetro de resize es una tupla de valores a los que quieres que se reescale la imagen, pero aun así da error